# File not being added to git

Tags: git

So there is one file in my git folders that just wont go into the git, it's not in the ignore list or anything and I have commited and pushed and pulled many times, and just noticed now that it hasn't been added. Is there any way to manually add just this one file?

Comment: ... _manually add just this one folder_ ... If your directory is empty, you can not add it to git, git does not understand directories. Just files

Comment: Did no one listen to what I said? Everything else in that folder is there, just this one *FILE* won't even add, it wasn't coming up in unversioned files or anything.

Comment: If you read the rest of the question you would have realised that "folder" was an accident at the end.

Comment: Can you please provide some more context? Does the filename contain any special characters or look similar to the name of another directory entry. How do you try to add the file? Do you see any messages when you try to do this?

Comment: The file was exactly the same as every other file. Nothing different in terms of formatting of file type, or code, or name or anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git add .` will add any files in the current directory and any sub-directories. I would imagine that you could also do `git add .\relative\path\to\file` as well. If the file still resists, force a change (add a new line somewhere in the file where it won't hurt anything) and try again. Sometimes the diff that git runs doesn't detect that the file has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You working on windows by any chance. 
I had a case the other day with a file

stub.c

in same directory 
So in windows, the file stub.c is always in modified state a no matter what I did I could not commit my changes.

So went to Unix and no problems at all (File system is case sensitive) 
Deleted Stub.c and everything worked like before.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As [Op De Cirkel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/742469/op-de-cirkel) [says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755613/file-not-being-added-to-git/13761755#comment18908862_13755613): you cannot add an empty folder to a Git repo since Git could only track files.

If you need this folder to be there for some reasons, go ahead and create an empty file there:

```
touch ./myemptyfolder/empty.txt
```

Once you've done this, you'll be able to

```
git add ./myemptyfolder
```

to your repo.